# Flask server stops working after 8 hours after running `nohup python app.py &`

Tags: python, linux, apache, flask

After SSHing into my cloud machine I'm running the command `nohup python app.py &` and then I type `disown`

It works well until 8 or so hours (sometimes more) when the server stops responding to requests. I am running on Apache if that helps and on an ip address with a port.

I'd like to point out that I do not see an application crash in the nohup output file which is concerning and I still see the process running when I run `ps -ef`

Comment: Why are you doing `nohup` at all? You can start a service that keeps your  server alive without intervention. http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/wsgi-standalone/

Comment: Do you see anything suspicious in syslog? `/var/log/syslog` for debian/ubuntu or `/var/log/messages` for centos/redhat. Also, is your app writing any logs? From what you described most likely you have not enough file descriptors.